# Google Custom Search most Popular queries to xml?

Tags: xml, api, google-custom-search

Is there any simple way to get via api/xml 10 most recent, or 10 most popular searched queries from Google Custom Search.

I have a buisness accountso i don't have to worry aboute any limitations.

Thank's for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so i did answer it by myself. 
You can get an RDF file, and then parse it by url

```
http://www.google.com/cse/api/YOUR_API_CODE/cse/YOUR_API_ID/queries?view=overal‌​l
```